# How to get subscribed topic at message arrive in mqtt?

Tags: java, mqtt

As an MQTT Client, I am subscribed to many topics.

When a message arrives, is it possible to know about which topic the message is for?

Comment: Please read the doc about how to ask a good question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it explains what you should include in a question)

Comment: Indeed, you don't provide any details to your question. Is it technical ? If yes, are you using Java ? Which library ?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the Paho Java MQTT client [doc](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttCallback.html#messageArrived-java.lang.String-org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage-)

```
void messageArrived(java.lang.String topic,
                    MqttMessage message)
             throws java.lang.Exception
```

This method is called to pass the arriving message to your code. The first argument is a String containing the topic.